# Android L - get all running apps which are visible via the Recents button (code)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Best,

I know that this kind of question has been asked for multiple times.
But because of the fact that I can't find a solution which satisfy my answer.
I'll ask it again.

How do you show / get all the active apps (via code) from your android device, **like** you would press on the "*recent*" button.

[image: resent button]

E.g. When I would perform the following actions:

- open Netflix
- press home button
- open settings
- press home button
- open camera
- press home button
- open open chrome
- press home button
- open MyApp

Then I would like to receive, in MyApp an list of all the open apps.

Thus : Netflix, settings, camera, chrome, MyApp

No more, no less, I do not want to see a list of apps which are running on the backgrond like e.g.

- Samsung keyboard
- Galaxy apps widget
- Messages
- S finder
- Weather
- ...
- OneDrive

(I've already tried RunningAppProcessInfo)

Comment: AFAIK, that data is not available to you [as of API Level 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: You can use this library to get a list of running apps on Android 5.0+: https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses UsageStatsManager might be your best option though.